# Seleccionar un radio button que pertenece a un grupo, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radiobutton

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente grupo de radios

```
<input type="radio" name="pedidos" val="1"></input>
<input type="radio" name="pedidos" val="2"></input>
<input type="radio" name="pedidos" val="3"></input>
<input type="radio" name="pedidos" val="4"></input>
```

Se que hay dos formas con jQuery dependiendo de la version, capturandolo por id

```
$("#id_radio").prop("checked", true);
$("#id_radio").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

en mi caso necesito es capturar el value del radio seleccionado, pero especificando el grupo, en este caso "pedidos", ya que puedo tener radios con el mismo value en otro grupo, como podria especificar esto, ya sea con Javascript o Jquery

Gracias!!

Comment: @masterguru lo que se necesita es seleccionarlo, como darle click a él, no obtener el valor del seleccionado, es posible hacer eso? es como cuando uno con Jquery selecciona el option de un select, seria lo mismo pero con el radio de un grupo de radios

Comment: @GabrielUribeGomez eso me pasa por leer en diagonal, cierto, gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 0):

Hay que aclarar primero que el atributo en el input deberia de ser value y no val

```
<input type="radio" name="pedidos" value="1"></input>
<input type="radio" name="pedidos" value="2"></input>
<input type="radio" name="pedidos" value="3"></input>
<input type="radio" name="pedidos" value="4"></input>
```

con JQuery puedes hacer un selector a los inputs con ese name

```
$("input[name=pedidos]:checked").val()
```

Para seleccionar el input con base al name y el value puedes usar el selector

```
$("input[name=pedidos][value='1']").prop("checked",true)
```

Comment: Hola, lo que dices es para capturar el seleccionado del grupo segun veo, correcto? lo que se necesita es que se seleccione, como si le dieramos click al radio

Comment: Oh, perdon, entendi que queria obtener el valor del seleccionado.

para seleccionarlo puede hacer un selector para el input con el name que necesite y el valor que quiere, como:

$("input[name=pedidos][value='1']").prop("checked",true)

Comment: @StialManstike [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/510933/edit) tu respuesta para poner lo que has dicho en el comentario pues, si funciona.

Comment: @StialManstike funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias

Comment: @masterguru listo, se agrego en la respuesta.

Comment: @RICARDOMEDINA Si esta respuesta da solución a tu pregunta debes aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede eternamente pendiente de respuesta. Si no sabes aceptarla mira [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200)